# List combinations and number of times they repeat in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure even exactly how to describe this issue, generally I have a small table (in SQL Server 2019) with 2 columns, not a lot of data, it looks like this

```
MechanicID       CarID
----------------------
1                   2
1                   3
2                   1
2                   3
4                   1
4                   2
4                   3
```

Now the idea is to (using SELECT preferably, maybe a stored procedure if SELECT is impossible?) check how many times does a certain combination of cars happen.

Basically it lists combinations of cars which were serviced together and the number of mechanics that serviced those combinations. Only those combinations that are existent should appear.

The result should be:

```
Car combination        Number of occurrences
---------------------------------------------
1&2                    1
1&3                    2
2&3                    2
```

So mechanic 1 has serviced cars 2&3, this combo has also been serviced by mechanic 4, so the number of occurrences is 2.

Help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What database do you use ?

Comment: MS SQL 2019 is the DB

Comment: Concatenation of data into a single column (as you're doing with the `Car combination` column) is not something easily done in SQL - as that's a data-display concern. Do you absolutely have to return data in that format or can you return normalized results?

Comment: Regrettably so normalized results are not the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self join and aggregation:

```
select t1.carid, t2.carid, count(*)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.MechanicID = t2.MechanicID and
        t1.carid < t2.carid
group by t1.carid, t2.carid
```

Comment: Great! https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0fea83f430617d3325ee94bc7f1aa1c6